# Vanilla Regex: is it possible to trim specific chars from the MIDDLE of a string with only regex?

Tags: regex, string

So currently I am working with a parsed yaml file that uses Regex to validate string values in a loan schema.

Specifically, right now I am working on postal code validation. I saw the post that provided a way to validate regex for postal codes that contain hyphens and spaces as well.

My current pattern, `^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?\s+$\g`, matches the following example formats, with either 5dig or 9dig zips accepted:

```
12345-1234
12345 1234
12345
```

I found this solution [here at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577236/regex-for-zip-code) and have since combined it with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064731/regex-to-trim-spaces-from-the-end-of-unknown-length-strings-of-words) to trim whitespace off the ends of the string.

While this originally fit the criteria, my company requested I replace/scrape any hyphens or spaces from the postal code value for the following output

```
12345-1234 -> 123451234
12345 1234 -> 123451234
 12345  -> 12345
```

I can do this directly in Java but, since I have developed a framework in Java that runs hundreds of different string validations, I'd like to avoid having to make a specific code block just for this one string validation.

Is there an efficient way for me to trim characters from the middle of a string using solely vanilla regex?

Comment: I know a lot about regex, but have never heard of yaml loan schema. I can't understand what you want.

Comment: regex doesn't change strings; it only matches them, or part of them, so to "trim" characters, you must write that tiny amount of java you're dreading: `str = str.replaceAll("(?<=^\\d{5})[-\\s](?=\\d{4}\\s*$", "");`

Comment: @Bohemian Well your statement is certainly true for the regex that is used in the answer the OP has linked to. But if you wanted to remove trailing blanks in a string and you were allowed to assume that the string contained at least one non-blank character, then you could match the string against `.*\S(?=\s*$)` and I would think that the matched string would be the original string without the trailing blanks. Of course, that's no help here.

Comment: So is this running under a java regex flavor? I can give you a .Net regex solution if you want to avoid Java....

Comment: Replacing all *non digits* `\D+` with empty, or am I missing something :S

Answer (score 1):

Java does support lookarounds, but if you are using replaceAll, you can also replace with 2 capture groups, as lookarounds can be costly. (There is no such thing as vanilla regex, there are a lot of different [regex engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines))

**Note** that `\s` can also match a newline, and `\s+` at the end matches 1 or more whitespace chars that might change the format of the yaml file.

Instead you might use `\h` to match horizontal whitespace chars.

Using `[-\s]` in the pattern matches a single char, being either `-` or a whitespace char. If there is always one of them present, and maybe more, you can also use a quantifier there.

```
^(\d{5})(?:[-\h]+(\d{4}))?\h+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aNmrRQ/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/BPfiyo)

```
String regex = "^(\\d{5})(?:[-\\h]+(\\d{4}))?\\h+$";
String string = "12345-1234 \n"
        + "12345 1234 \n"
        + "12345 ";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("$1$2"));
```

Output

```
123451234
123451234
12345
```

Comment: I like your answers TFB, just want to say, good job !

Comment: @sln Thanks, very much appreciated coming from a regex expert like you :-)